# Cast Error in ORDER BY Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have this query that causes an error:

> Cannot convert from nvarchar to bigint

But only on the ORDER BY area.

```
SELECT TOP (25)  
    CAST(AttrValue AS BIGINT) AttrValue 
FROM 
    tblattributevalue AS attVal WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    tblattribute AS att WITH (NOLOCK) ON Att.AttrID = attVal.AttrID
                                      AND att.AttrName = 'Rank Gold'
LEFT JOIN 
    #books AS P ON P.BookID = attVal.BookId
WHERE 
    attVal.GenreID = @GenreID
    AND attVal.Active = 1
    AND att.Active = 1
    AND P.BookID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    CAST(AttrValue AS BIGINT)
```

If I comment out the `ORDER BY`, it works just fine. The top casting works and is using the same data. The data displayed is:

```
AttrValue:
28,
24,
2,
6,
89,
27,
1,
4,
234,
3,
7,
9
```

Any ideas as to why it converts on `SELECT` but not on `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Just try by giving `.....order by 1;`.

Comment: Remove the cast, you have a value that can not be converted to big int. Why do you have a cast in an order clase this will destroy the hope to use an index.....dont use any function in the left side of a criteria or an order by

Comment: The first 25 results (unordered) are all able to be cast to bigint, which causes no error. When you choose to order, it has to cast them all before sorting and you have at least one value in there that cannot be cast to bigint. This causes the error.

Comment: All rows have to be converted to BigInt so that the TOP clause knows which 25 rows to return.  To identity the problems, try "Select AttrValue From TableName Where IsNumeric(AttrValue) = 0'

Comment: This specific Genre only has 12 values for the AttrName given, with or without TOP 25 it gives the same values. The SELECT AttrValue gives me the values I included above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you ALL for the responses but for some reason my values were not converting on the `ORDER BY` clause. What did worked was putting everything into a temp table then ordering from there.

```
SELECT 
CAST(AttrValue as BIGINT) AttrValue
,BookID
INTO #sortBooks
FROM tblattributevalue AS attVal WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblattribute AS att WITH (NOLOCK) ON Att.AttrID = attVal.AttrID
            AND att.AttrName = 'Rank Gold'
LEFT JOIN #books AS P ON P.BookID = attVal.BookId
WHERE attVal.GenreID = @GenreID
AND attVal.Active = 1
AND att.Active = 1
AND P.BookID IS NOT NULL
```

Then, I grabbed those values to be ordered.

```
SELECT TOP (25) BookID
FROM #sortBooks
ORDER BY AttValue
```

Since for some reason it wasn't casting on the `ORDER BY` for some Genres and others it was. But it was allowing casting on the `SELECT` then I place everything on temp table and used that to ordered the Books. This is what work on my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is returning the `TOP 25`, but when you `ORDER BY` something you get a conversion error. If you drop the `ORDER BY`, you get a different set of data (obviously...), but no conversion error.

When casting, all of the values must first be converted, then ordered.  So somewhere in your list of values, there's something that cannot be converted to a `BIGINT` data type.

Try running this query:

```
SELECT AttrValue 
FROM tblattributevalue AS attVal WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblattribute AS att WITH (NOLOCK) ON Att.AttrID = attVal.AttrID
            AND att.AttrName = 'Rank Gold'
LEFT JOIN #books AS P ON P.BookID = attVal.BookId
WHERE attVal.GenreID = @GenreID
AND attVal.Active = 1
AND att.Active = 1
AND P.BookID IS NOT NULL
AND ISNUMERIC(AttrValue) = 0
```

**EDIT:**

Another important consideration when checking is that certain special characters like commas, periods, dollar signs, and hyphens count as numeric values, but might pose a problem for certain conversions.  For an example, run this:

```
CREATE TABLE NumericTestTable (String NVARCHAR(55))
;
INSERT INTO NumericTestTable (string) VALUES (N'1234567890')
;
INSERT INTO NumericTestTable (string) VALUES (N'$1234567890')
;
INSERT INTO NumericTestTable (string) VALUES (N'12.34567890')
;
INSERT INTO NumericTestTable (string) VALUES (N'-1234567890')
;
INSERT INTO NumericTestTable (string) VALUES (N't1234567890')
;
INSERT INTO NumericTestTable (string) VALUES (N'1*234567890')
;
INSERT INTO NumericTestTable (string) VALUES (N'@1234567890')
;
INSERT INTO NumericTestTable (string) VALUES (N'#1234567890')
;
SELECT string, ISNUMERIC(string) FROM NumericTestTable
;
SELECT string, ISNUMERIC(string), CAST(string AS BIGINT) 
FROM NumericTestTable 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(string) = 1
; 
/* Returns error: 
Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.. 
Error 8114. SQLSTATE 42000. Severity 16. MsgState 5. Line 1.
*/
```

Comment: And if you're curious to see what your error-making values are :  SELECT 'Problem Values' as MyCol, AttrValue 
FROM tblattributevalue AS attVal WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tblattribute AS att WITH (NOLOCK) ON Att.AttrID = attVal.AttrID
            AND att.AttrName = 'Rank Gold'
LEFT JOIN #books AS P ON P.BookID = attVal.BookId
WHERE attVal.GenreID = @GenreID
AND attVal.Active = 1
AND att.Active = 1
AND P.BookID IS NOT NULL
AND ISNUMERIC(AttrValue) != 0

Comment: Actually, `ISNUMERIC() = 0` specifically means 'Return values that are not numeric', i.e. `ISNUMERIC('123t5')` = 0, so the query I wrote should return the problematic values.

Comment: The datatype of the column is NVARCHAR, when using ISNUMERIC it returns nothing. When using !=, like @granadaCoder suggested, it returns the values. But, we want the set result to be ORDER BY AttValue. This specific Genre, has only 12  Books with "Rank Gold" as AttrName. I can see the values being returned, listed above, they have only numbers. The CAST on the SELECT works but not on the ORDER BY.

Comment: Now I'm confused... we are talking about SQL Server, right? If I create a table with an NVARCHAR(55) column, and insert two rows, one with just numbers and one with a few other characters thrown in, the `ISNUMERIC()` function returns either a 1 (the value is numeric) or a 0 (the value contains non-numeric characters) as expected... Working in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I see what you meant, I placed the ISNUMERIC() on the WHERE not on the SELECT. But when placing it at the top everything returned is 1. And, yes SQL Server.

Comment: The `ISNUMERIC()` should be in the `WHERE` clause, because we're trying to find a value that can't be converted to `BIGINT`.  You're going to want to make sure that you remove the `TOP 25` from the `SELECT` to ensure that you're scanning the entire table for a non-numeric value in the column you want to `ORDER BY`.

Comment: My apologies.  I got my = and != backwards.   IsNumeric = 0 means "not a number" !  So my above query should be adjusted.         Here is the documentation quote: "ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0. Valid numeric data types include the following:"

Comment: @granadaCoder No worries. I'm updating my answer with another consideration.

Comment: I checked my values and they are with no punctuation or chars. I found a solution to this specific issue. Will post my answer.